# Error while executing sudo sh./usertest.sh

Tags: command-line

I faced an error during the Setup software at Raspberry Pi; 
While executing the command line in raspberry Pi shell, `sudo sh ./usertest.sh` I got the following errors .

```
detec_fb_type :unknown device type
[ERROR][FILE] iso=-1:javacall_file_sizeof() Problem getting information
```

I'll be grateful if somebody can help :)